# How to import different package according to predefined variable or in config.properties?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have already built an end-to-end test automation for my company's web application that is using Dojo framework. I am using Cucumber, Selenium, in Java and using JUnit runner to run my automation. In the next version, they are changing to AngularJs framework. The plan is to use the same repo and split the package into two version which are Dojo and Angular since the backend are the same, only the ui is different. This is because I think it will be easier to maintain.

```
Package before:
    - glue
    - page
```

```
Package after :
    - glue
    - page
        - dojo
        - angular
```

My solution is to put the ui build in the config.properties.

```
config.properties

ui.build=dojo
```

My question is how to use this properties to let the glue codes knows in which package it should import? Is there a better solution for my problems?

My other solution is to create a new runner for both angular build and dojo build and duplicate all and put it in different packages but that will make it hard to maintain.

I expect the glue codes to import in dojo package if the ui.build is in dojo and vice versa, but I don't know how to do that? I tried googling but I can't find any answer for it.

Let me know if you guys need additional informations.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough research, I found that it is impossible. I think the best way is to use interface and just change both of the Dojo and Angular class to implement and create a new method to handle the class pass.

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible when using [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can configure step provider pakage using property `step.provider.pkg`. You can have different package configured for different xml test set as well. Refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html), it shows examples with bdd2 factory and also works for ghekin factory.

```
step.provider.pkg=some.common;page.dojo
```

For angulare

```
step.provider.pkg=some.common;page.angular
```

To set `step.provider.pkg`, there are [different ways of providing property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html)